# Python Automated Web Page downloading, with Username, Password and Cookies

Tags: python, cookies, web, passwords

I'm trying to implement in Python a simple program that reads rom web pages and writes them to files. There are about 2000 pages of messages incrementally numbered, but some numbers are missing.

The Web site is username and password protected, and I'm using the same username and password I normally use to access it manually. I'm using some code examples with cookie handling I found in the official Python web site, but when I try them the website I'm trying to copy replies

> "Your browser is not accepting our cookies. To view this page, please set your browser preferences to accept cookies. (Code 0)"

Obviously there is a problem with cookies, and perhaps I'm not handling username and password correctly. Any suggestion regarding the following code?

```
import urllib2
import cookielib
import string
import urllib
def cook():
    url="http://www.URL.com/message/"
    cj = cookielib.LWPCookieJar()
    authinfo = urllib2.HTTPBasicAuthHandler()
    realm = "http://www.URL.com"
    username = "ID"
    password = "PSWD"
    host = "http://www.URL.com/message/"
    authinfo.add_password(realm, host, username, password)
    opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj), authinfo)
    urllib2.install_opener(opener)

    # Create request object
    txheaders = { 'User-agent' : "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.5; Windows NT)" }
    try:
        req = urllib2.Request(url, None, txheaders)
        cj.add_cookie_header(req)
        f = urllib2.urlopen(req)

    except IOError, e:
        print "Failed to open", url
        if hasattr(e, 'code'):
            print "Error code:", e.code

    else:

        print f

cook
url="http://www.URL.com/message/"
urllib.urlretrieve(url + '1', 'filename')
```

Comment: An alternative rather than a solution: use the mechanize library http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/

Comment: Not a solution either, but if you're looking at scraping HTML with python and don't know about [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup), it is extremely useful.